# How to read and split the contents of txt file in Java?

Tags: java, file, text, split

I want to read the whole text of a file and then split it according to specific delimiters.
How could I do so in Java?

Comment: to split the file there should be one condition. either you want to split based on size[bytes] / delimeter .

Please complete the question

Answer (score 3):

```
try{
  // Open the file
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
  // Get the object of DataInputStream
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;
  //Read File Line By Line
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // split the line on your splitter(s)
     String[] splitted = strLine.split("-"); // here - is used as the delimiter
  }
  //Close the input stream
  in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

Comment: But why I should read the text line by line? That may cause errors in my results , since it will also spitted in extra positions, which is the end of the lines!!

Answer (score 0):

Read the contents. Choose a delimiter up to which you want to check each line/word or phrase for the splitting. Have a switch case setup. Whatever content you find based on the switch case you can perform actions. Say you can write in different text files from different cases.